# If $x>2$, $m$ the least integer larger than $x$, $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$, then $(1+1/(x+1))^{-1}(1+1/m)^m≤(1+1/x)^x≤(1+1/(x-1))(1+1/n)^n$

Tags: inequality

> $(1+{1\over x+1})^{-1}(1+{1\over m})^m≤(1+{1\over x})^x≤(1+{1\over x-1})(1+{1\over n})^n$
>   where $x>2$ and $x \in \Bbb R $
>    and $m$ is the least integer larger than $x$ and $n$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$

I can prove the right hand inequality by substituting n with $x$ and $x-1$,
$(1+{1\over x-1})(1+{1\over n})^n>(1+{1\over x})(1+{1\over x})^{x-1}=(1+{1\over x})^x$

But this trick doesn't work on the left hand inequaltiy.
If I substitute m with $x$ and $x+1$,I get
 $(1+{1\over x+1})^{-1}(1+{1\over m})^m<(1+{1\over x+1})^{-1}(1+{1\over x})^{x+1}$ which is larger than$(1+{1\over x})^x$

Can anyone give me some tips on that?Thanks!

Comment: It's my mistake,I edited the question

Comment: @Charles Corrected. Now it might well be the case that the OP actually meant $m=\lceil x\rceil$...

Comment: Are you assuming $x$ is an integer? Are you defining $m$ as being $m>x$, always?

Comment: @Did Yes, I was wondering if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ or not..

Comment: @Charles ((Anyway, thanks for your now deleted comment.))

Comment: @Did I generally delete comments pertaining to edits, that are then addressed, since the comment is no longer relevant, IMO.

Comment: $x \in \Bbb R$ instead of $ x ∈ \Bbb N$

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove

$$\left(1+{1\over x+1}\right)^{-1}\left(1+{1\over m}\right)^m≤\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^x$$

$$\left(1+{1\over m}\right)^m≤\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^x\left(1+{1\over x+1}\right).$$

Since $m>x$, it suffices to prove

$$\left(1+{1\over m}\right)^m≤\left(1+{1\over m}\right)^x\left(1+{1\over x+1}\right)$$

$$\left(1+{1\over m}\right)^{m-x}≤1+{1\over x+1}$$

$$1+{1\over m}≤\left(1+{1\over x+1}\right)^{1\over {m-x}}.$$

Since $m-x\le 1$, by generalized Bernoulli inequality,
$$\left(1+{1\over x+1}\right)^{1\over {m-x}}\ge 1+{1\over x+1}\cdot {1\over m-x}.$$

So it suffices to prove that

$$1+{1\over x+1}\cdot {1\over {m-x}}\ge 1+{1\over m}$$

$$m\ge (x+1)(m-x)$$

$$x^2+x\ge mx$$

$$x+1\ge m,$$ which is true.